# Nginx: rewrite rule for path

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-location

I have url http://myhost.com/admin3
I need redirect any path ../admin3/✽✽/✽ to ../admin3
I set in my config

```
location / {
        ^/admin3/?(.*)$ /$1 break;
    }
```

But it doesn't work. In case e.g. http://myhost.com/admin3/grthr I got 404 Not Found

Comment: Aside from whatever Nginx misconfiguration you are suffering from, your regex is wrong and would match `/admin3333333`. You need `^/admin3(?:/.*)?$`

Comment: Per https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms you could use `location /admin3 {}` to make your life simpler.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus looks like regex that you provided works. I've tested it on fresh installed nginx, and on dev instance. Thank's for your help!